# hiding the TRibbon ScreenTipsWindow

Tags: delphi, ribbon

how can I hide the TRibbon ScreenTipsWindow whenever I need to?  the product manager doesn't like the fact that the ribbon's ScreenTipsWindow stays visible even after a button is clicked.

I looked at this for a while and found that everything I would have used to hide that window is "private"!

thank you for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't experimented with it myself but `TScreenTipsWindow` has a `HideHint` procedure so if you can obtain a reference to the ScreenTipsWindow.

`TScreenTipsWindow` decends from `THintWindow` so if you can't get a reference to the object or calling `TScreenTipsWindow.HideHint` doesn't work you may be able to call `Application.HideHint` or `Application.CancelHint`.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  it doesn't listen to Application.HideHint or Application.CancelHint.  it also has the window private.